# Searching a user inputted array in lisp

Tags: lisp

How does one go about searching a user inputted array in Lisp ?

some general guidance would be very useful!

Thanks!

Should i use "member" or "find" ?

```
(defun enterl()  
  (princ "Enter First Number")
  (setq userInput (read-line))
  (setf num1 (parse-integer userInput))
  (member num1 '(5 9 1 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of those if you are after it's there or not. `member` will give you the whole sublist with the `first` element be the searched term while `find` only gives you the searched term when found. `find` works on every sequence so it's a more general function. eg. You can find a letter in a string since a string is a sequence of letters.

```lisp
;; example data
(defparameter *haystack* '("one" nil "two" "three" "four"))
(defparameter *needle* "two")

;; with find
(find *needle* *haystack* :test #'equal) ; ==> "two"

;; with member
(member *needle* *haystack* :test #'equal) ; ==> ("two" "three" "four")
```

However if you are searching for a empty value you need to use `member`

```lisp
;; with find you can't find nil since it's the default result when the item is not found
(find nil *haystack* :test #'equal) ; ==> nil
(find "not-there" *haystack* :test #'equal) ; ==> nil

;; with member you see the difference since you get the cons which is a true value
(member nil *haystack* :test #'equal) ; ==> (nil "two" "three" "four")
(member "not-there" *haystack* :test #'equal) ; ==> nil
```

Sometimes they won't be the tool for the job. Eg. if you are after at which index the item was found you might need to use `loop`, `reduce`, or roll your own recursion instead.

**EDIT**

`read-line` returns a string with everything you have entered. Thus you won't get an array or list of elements from that at all but one string you need to [split it into values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440679/1565698). `read` is the same function that reads code so if your input is valid LISP data you're good. eg. If you enter `(1 2 3)` to `read` you get a list with 3 numbers.

Instead of using `setq` and `setf` you can use local bindings with `let`. Eg.

```lisp
(let ((list (progn (princ "Enter list Eg. (1 2 3): ") (read)))
      (item (progn (princ "Enter an item to search: ") (read))))
  ;; here you have list and item bound
  (member item list :test #'equal))
```

Notice you can abstract away the `progn` by making a function that presents a string, then call `read`.

Comment: Im sorry but could you help me by applying those examples to a user input ?

Like 
Enter array

Comment: @Fergo It really depends on what format you are using. If you expect  a valid structure then you can use `(read)`. Since you were asking whether to use `member` or `find` and were very sparse on details I expected you had got that part already.

Comment: Sorry im actually a complete novice at Lisp. 

So if i started with somthing like this: 

(defun enterl()  (princ "Enter First Number")
              (setq userInput (read-line))
              (setf num1 (parse-integer userInput))
              (member num1 '(5 9 1 2)))

would i be starting of the right track ?

i just want to be able to enter an array, preferablely a size specified by the user and then search the user inputted array with a user input, is this even possible in Lisp? nee trying for a few days and made little progress.